# MVC 4 using JQuery Mobile - cannot upload file using post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file to MVC 4 Internet Mobile Project (from the template..)
anyway, the code works fine until i add the JQuery Mobile library to the page and the file is passed null to the controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)  
                                        --> file is null when using JQuery Mobile
```

Can someone show an example for how to enable the post to receive files ?

EDIT: from another check i did, it seems that when a file is picked from the file system, it comes out as null. 
checked it with javscript to see what happens when the file is changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery Mobile AJAXifies forms and as you already know it is not possible to upload files using AJAX. As a workaround you could add the `data-ajax="false"` attribute to your `<form>` element to prevent jQuery Mobile from hijacking it and using AJAX.